# Tame fundamental group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology

Let $X$ be a normal and flat scheme over $Spec(\mathbb{Z})$. We know a good way to compute the etale fundamental group of $X$. Can we say sth similar for the tame fundamental group. If so, what would it be? For example, I am trying to compute the $\pi^t_1(Spec(\mathbb{Z}_f))$ where by $\mathbb{Z}_f = \{ \frac{a}{f^n}: a,n \in \mathbb{Z}, n>0\}$. I guess, It should be the Ray class group relative to the modulus $\Pi_{p \nmid f}p$.

Thank you!

Comment: When you say "compute the etale fundamental group" do you mean "describe as a union of infinitely many extensions", or is there actually a good computational model?

Comment: @Carnahan, no as you said just to describe it ...